# Bootstrap. How to change styles for different col-* sizes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I change for example a text-size in Bootstrap while resize the browser window? Or how to make it smaller if col-xs and bigger if col-md?

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
text
</div>
```

Should I use:

```
@media (min-width: 991px) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes using media query you can do this.

HTML :

```
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 sometext">
        text
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and(min-width: 991px) {
    .sometext {
       font-size:10px ; //for example
    }
}
```

[Refer this for more information on media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: I think it should be 'min-width: 992px' as bootstrap shows the smaller screen layout at 991px (for col-md) but '.sometext' will still be applied then if 'min-width: 991px' is used. This would only affects screens that are exactly 991px wide so maybe not a big issue!

Answer (score 1):

I run into this frequently (usually to change text alignment based on media size) and this is the approach I use with bootstrap.  Right off the bat, the only downside is that the content in the div is replicated.  However, this is easily solvable by storing the content as a Razor variable or using jQuery. I don't necessarily like that this approach, but I have found it to be the best way to solve this problem.

Also another thing to note is that when using bootstrap I often explicitly write each of the four bootstrap media size cases just to throw out the interpretive guess work, even if it is redundant.

```
.sometext {
    font-size: 10px;
    }

<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 hidden-md hidden-lg">
text
</div>

<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-3 col-lg-3 sometext">
text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `vw units`.

For example, with a `<p>` tag:

```
p {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-size: 3.5vw;
}
```

Or ..

```
h1 {
  font-size: 5.9vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.0vh;
}
p {
  font-size: 2vmin;
}
```

See [Viewport Sized Typography](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)